# Can I get all drop down whose id contains 20_Voucher_Saved_ and selected value "no" in each statement?

Tags: jquery

Can I get all drop down whose id contains 20_Voucher_Saved_ and selected value "no" in each statement using jquery?

```
$("select[id*='20_Voucher_Saved_']").each(function (i, el) {

});
```

I know I can use alert(el.value) to get the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put some logic in `.filter()` and select only the elements you want

```
$("select[id*='20_Voucher_Saved_']")
      .filter(function(){return this.value === 'no';}).each(function(){ ... });
```

If your `<option>` elements do have a value attribute you can filter directly in the selector

```
$("select[id*='20_Voucher_Saved_']:has(option[value='no']:selected)")
  .each(function(){ ... });
```

Between these two, `.filter()` will most likely be faster.